# Should I take a relational or multidimensional/ OLAP approach to a stock market historical analysis project?

Tags: ssas, data-mining, olap, ssas-2008

this isn't a syntax/ coding specific question per se, but I'm unable to find any real articles online of any significance that speak to it directly. As I begin to delve into data mining using Sql Server Analysis Services (2008R2), I am wondering if I should be taking a relational data approach (as my data currently exists) or begin with an OLAP model. I am studying daily stock market data on 5,000 symbols. This translates to 12 tables or so, low millions of rows each. At my basic, current understanding, OLAP seems like an extra layer of complexity added that I don't see justified. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts...

Putting in place an OLAP model is offereing great potential for sophisticated data analysis using MDX. MDX is quite a powerfull language with higher level concepts than SQL (e.g., different types of aggregations (e.g, open/close), hierarchical dimensions, functional language, drilldown, calculated measures etc...). Perhaps in the future, as the volume of your data will increase you might get some performance issues with raw SQL; the OLAP 
cube should be faster then.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I thought my project was going in that direction, I just wanted a little input before I went down the path.

Comment: I would add that another aspect of the OLAP model that is helpful is that the MDX language also better supports time-series analysis: this year/last year, quarter over quarter growth, cumulative (MTD, YTD), and so on. If you're performing this type of analysis, the queries are much easier to write (once you learn MDX) and perform much better with the OLAP model as compared to the relational model.